Problems with multiple superposing plots
I want to plot the following:
$$ f(y) = -\frac{z}{4\pi} \frac{1}{x^2(\sqrt{x^2+1})}\left(y^2 -\frac{1}{y^2}\right)$$
but $z,y$ are constrained as follows: $z\in(0,0.5 x^2]$ and
$$y(z) = \dfrac{x^2}{2z}\left[1 + \sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{2z}{x^2} \right)^2}\right]  $$
Furthermore, my values for $x$ are $x=0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8$. I am able to superimpose plots of $y(z)$ for different values of $x$ using advise from this thread: Multiple graphs in one plot, with a variable in the plot range. However, when I try to do it for the function above, it turns up a bunch of errors about something not being a machine sizeable number, and it involves the expression $\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{2z}{x^2} \right)^2} $

Please edit the question and include your Mathematica code.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

y[z_] := x^2/(2 z) (1 + Sqrt[1 - (2 z/x^2)^2]);

funcs = ConditionalExpression[y[z] /. x -> #, z <= #^2/2] & /@
   Range[1/5, 4/5, 1/5] // Simplify


Plot[funcs, {z, 0, 8/25},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {z, y}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[Range[0.2, 0.8, 0.2],
    LegendLabel -> Style["x", 14]],
   {.5, .6}]]


EDIT: Continuing,
f[y_] := -z/(4 Pi) 1/(x^2 Sqrt[x^2 + 1]) (y^2 - 1/y^2)

funcs2 = ConditionalExpression[f[y[z]] /. x -> #,
     z <= #^2/2] & /@ Range[1/5, 4/5, 1/5] // FullSimplify


Plot[funcs2, {z, 0, 8/25},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {z, f}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[Range[0.2, 0.8, 0.2],
    LegendLabel -> Style["x", 14]],
   {.5, .4}]]


EDIT 2: To plot f vs y use ParametricPlot
funcs3 = ConditionalExpression[
     {y[z], f[y[z]]} /. x -> #, z <= #^2/2] & /@
   Range[1/5, 4/5, 1/5] // FullSimplify


ParametricPlot[funcs3, {z, 0, 8/25},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@
    {HoldForm@y[z], HoldForm@f[y[z]]}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[Range[0.2, 0.8, 0.2],
    LegendLabel -> Style["x", 14],
    LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn"],
   {.75, .65}]]



How do I get the 2nd plot to be plotted as f vs y[z] instead of f vs z?
